# How can we use `names()` or an alternative to name `reactiveVal` inside Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, names

I tried to use `names()` on a `reactiveVal` inside a shiny app without success.

---

Is this even possible? What are alternative ways to *name* reactive values in shiny apps?

---

My first attempt throws an error:

```
names(r()) <- "something"
```

> Error in names(r()) <- "something" :    invalid (NULL) left side of
>   assignment

My second attempt as well:

```
names(r) <- "something"
```

> Error in names(r) <- "something" : names() applied to a non-vector

---

Here is a minimal example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(textOutput("text")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  r <- reactiveVal(1)
  # names(r) <- "something"
  output$text <- renderText(
    paste0("The reactiveVal is ", r(),". It's name is ", names(r()),"."))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the documentation on how to set values. From the docs:

`Call the function with no arguments to (reactively) read the value; call the function with a single argument to set the value.`

This means it gets a little bit esoteric and I personally prefer to use magrittr aliases and a pipe to keep things readable. The key steps for setting the names of your reactive value later on are:

- call it with no arguments `r()`, to read the current value.
- wrap the call in `isolate` to prevent any reactivity on this step
- pass the returned value to `set_names` along with the name string.
- call the reactive value `r` again with the named value as an argument, to set `r`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(textOutput("text")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  r <- reactiveVal(1 %>% set_names("something")) #setting the name on initial

  isolate(r()) %>% 
    set_names("something else") %>%  
    r()
  output$text <- renderText(
    paste0("The reactiveVal is ", r(),". It's name is ", names(r()),"."))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You cannot name a variable in R; the concept simply does not make sense within R.

If you want to provide a better label for a variable for when you present it, there are dozens of ways of doing, depending on how you are presenting the variable.

For a `reactiveVal` in Shiny, you can assign a "label" (`reactiveVal(value, label="my super reactive")`), but that is only for debugging purposes.

If you want to assign a named index to the elements of a vector, i.e.

```
a <- 1:3
names(a) <- c('Bob','Foo','Bar')
a
# Bob Foo Bar 
#  1   2   3
```

but the variable is wrapped in a reactive, assign the naming inside the reactive:

```
r <- reactiveVal(structure(1, .Names='something'))
```

Or from a `observe`:

```
a <- 1:3
names(a) <- c('Bob','Foo','Bar')
r(a) ## assigns a value to the reactive
```

#### Update in response to comment

> What do you mean with *You cannot name a variable in R; the concept simply does not make sense within R.*? Isn't using names() exactly naming a variable? ..I don't get it. Can you explain this a little further?

What is the name of a variable? It's the symbol we use to address it. In the examples above I'm using `a` and `r` for two distinct names/symbols for two distinct variables.

The function `names()` refers to setting and getting the names of a variable's entries, elements and columns. For an atomic vector or list (`a <- c(1, 2, 3); names(a) <- c('a','b','c')`) this becomes identical to a named index (or key-value pair for lists), where 'a', 'b' and 'c' are used to refer to specific entries within `a`, with the added benefit that 'a', 'b' and 'c' can be referenced by a variable itself.

So `names` refers to a property* of the object referenced by the variable. When you assign a value to a reactive with `r <- reactiveVal(1)`, `r` refers to a reactive object that holds an atomic vector with a single element of value "1".
`names(r)` is not defined for a reactive object.

*: Technically, it's an attribute. Try `attr(a)` and see.

Comment: What do you mean with *You cannot name a variable in R; the concept simply does not make sense within R.*? Isn't using `names()` exactly *naming* a variable? ..I don't get it. Can you explain this a little further?

Comment: Updated answer to your comment.